# Problems watch variables in the free STVD IDE while debugging code on STM8 MCUs

Tags: microcontroller

Has anyone worked with ST Microelectronics STM8 8-bit MCUs and ST's free STVD IDE (COSMIC compiler) to write and debug code for them?  I'm so frustrated with it while debugging.  I set variables from constants and otherwise and see the watch window report totally different numbers.  The problem also seems to have to do with conversions from integers to floats.  float to int seems ok.  Notice in the attached that the variable 'delb' has been declared as a 16 bit unsigned integer and set to 1, and that code has clearly just been executed.  Yet, the watch window and the memory window say its value is '0'.  I can't tell if the discrepancy is due to the debugger, firmware or what.  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong or what's happening?  Thanks.

[image: Watch variable problem]

Comment: It doesn't seem like you're using that variable. It's likely that the compiler has optimized that initialization away because it has no effect.

Comment: Oh yes, the optimizer.  Good idea.  In Project->Settings->C Compiler, I changed optimizations to 'Disable for Debugging'.  I think that was it.  Bless you, brhans!

Comment: But how can I 'use' the variable to guarantee that the optimizer doesn't optimize it into oblivion without warning?  Would, for example, incrementing it in the next line do so, or is the optimizer smart enough to detect that subterfuge?  How far do I have to go to outwit the optimizer?  I went into Project Settings under the C Compiler tab and set Optimizations to Disable for Debugging.  But that doesn't seem to help.